# Error al cargar JsonArray Android Studio

Tags: java, android, jsonobject, jsonarray

Deseo generar un JsonObject en el cual el value de uno de sus campos contenga un JsonArray.
Como resultado de una consulta obtengo un cursor que me devuelve los detalles que necesito agregar. Intento recorrer el cursor agregando cada uno de los codigos y tipo de movimientos a un JsonArray de la siguiente forma:

```
    RemitoDet remitodet;

    JSONObject object=new JSONObject();

    object.put("id_mandatario",1);
    object.put("id_cliente",1234);
    object.put("estado","A");      

    JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();

    Cursor c = ObtenerDetalle(1);// Obtengo el detalle para el id_mandatario = 1

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

     do {
         remitodet = new RemitoDet(c.getString(0), c.getString(1));

         obj.put("cod", remitodet.getCodigo());
         obj.put("tipo_mov", remitodet.getMovimiento());

         array.put(obj);


     } while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    object.put("detalle", array);
```

El inconveniente que estoy teniendo es que cada vez que se ejecuta el

```
array.put(obj);
```

repite el detalle. Ej:

```
{
"id_mandatario" : 1, 
"id_cliente" : 1234, 
"est" : "A" , 
"detalle" : [
            {
                "cod":"001",
                "tipo_mov":"R"
             },
             {
                "cod":"001",
                "tipo_mov":"R"
            },
             {
                "cod":"001",
                "tipo_mov":"R"
            }
         ]
}
```

Cuando lo que espero es por Ej:

```
{
"id_mandatario" : 1, 
"id_cliente" : 1234, 
"est" : "A" , 
"detalle" : [
            {
                "cod":"123",
                "tipo_mov":"E"
             },
             {
                "cod":"658",
                "tipo_mov":"H"
            },
             {
                "cod":"001",
                "tipo_mov":"R"
            }
         ]
}
```

**Vale aclarar que:**
1) Siempre repite el ultimo obj generado.
2) Verifiqué que el ObtenerDetalle(1) devuelva códigos distintos y tipo de movimientos distintos
3) El JsonObject obj se carga con los valores correctos antes de ser agregado al array.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
do {
         obj=new JSONObject();
         remitodet = new RemitoDet(c.getString(0), c.getString(1));

         obj.put("cod", remitodet.getCodigo());
         obj.put("tipo_mov", remitodet.getMovimiento());

         array.put(obj);


     } while(c.moveToNext());
```

Te explico, como trabajas con objetos, al momento de hacer "array.put(obj)" estas pasando una referencia del objeto 'obj' inicializado antes del ciclo While, pero al inicializar la variable cada que repites el ciclo generas un espacio nuevo en memoria y por lo tanto al momento de hacer esto: "array.put(obj)" colocas cada vez una referencia distinta.
Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Exacto. No estaba creando una nueva instancia del objeto. Gracias David!!